# Looking for ddos testing tools

Tags: linux, testing, ddos

I'm looking for a toolkit to test how my website will react to a DOS/DDOS attack. The only tool I know so far, is Low Orbit Ion Cannon. However, I don't know how this one compares to any other tools avaliable. Also, I'd love the ability to run it from the command line on linux.

Which DDOS tools would you recommend for me?

I prefer open source, unless the alternative is significantly better

Answer (score 3):

Normally, "real" testing against a DDOS attack or, just heavy traffic in general, is referred to as "load testing". Perhaps google will yield better results from those keywords.

I use LoadStorm--it's been reliable and I would recommend it.

Answer (score -1):

Fearboot.com is a good place for that.

Comment: It seems it became invalid